# What's the C#-idiomatic way to set a member during construction?

Tags: c#, constructor, idioms

I find myself writing a lot of code that looks like this:

```
 new Foo(7, "a");
```

where `Foo` looks like:

```
 class Foo {
      int bar;
      string baz;
      public Foo(int bar, string baz) {
           this.bar = bar;
           this.baz = baz;
      }
 }
```

How would a C#-trained programmer go about this?  Writing `this.bar = bar` and `this.baz = baz` works, but it feels odd.

Comment: Thats pretty much it, there are a few different ways of doing it, but none of them are really faster. Most logic doesn't go into constructors all that often so its not that bad

Comment: bar and baz are class variables. For properties you need to define setters and getters. You can either use a set; get; or use a private variable to store values. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287786%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: @Tarik fields are fine for private members (which `bar` and `baz` are by default).  If `bar` and `baz` were public I'd agree with you.

Comment: @DStanley I might sound a bit pedentic here but my understanding is that properties are only so if defined using accessors otherwise they are class members. There are instances where this distinction makes a difference: example when binding to a list of objects, you can bind to properties but not public members.

Comment: @Tarik I think you misunderstand the OP .. both properties and fields are "members" - you're talking about fields vs properties, but calling fields "members".

Comment: @Blorgbeard right, a property is a member but not vise versa.

Comment: @Tarik ah I just noticed the title's been edited.. that might explain it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A popular convention is to prefix private field names with `_`, differentiating them from common parameter names, e.g.

```
class Foo {
      int _bar;
      string _baz;
      public Foo(int bar, string baz) {
           _bar = bar;
           _baz = baz;
      }
 }
```

The use of `this` is then unnecessary. Alternatively, since you mention *properties* in the question title, you can encapsulate those fields in properties and set them:

```
class Foo {
      int _bar;
      string _baz;
      public Foo(int bar, string baz) {
           Bar = bar;
           Baz = baz;
      }

    public int Bar
    {
        get { return _bar; }
        set { _bar = value; }
    }

    public string Baz
    {
        get { return _baz; }
        set { _baz = value; }
    }
}
```

Since C# has case-sensitive symbol names, `this` remains unnecessary. Now, if you're not doing anything more complicated than this with the properties' get/set behaviour, you can eliminate the field declarations entirely with *auto-property syntax*:

```
class Foo {
    public Foo(int bar, string baz) {
           Bar = bar;
           Baz = baz;
      }

    public int Bar { get; set; }

    public string Baz { get; set; }
}
```

Now, if you have the common requirement that these properties can be read from outside the class but can only be set from within, you can make them readonly:

```
class Foo {
    public Foo(int bar, string baz) {
           Bar = bar;
           Baz = baz;
      }

    public int Bar { get; private set; }

    public string Baz { get; private set; }
}
```

But if you want them to truly only be set in the constructor, you go back to using fields:

```
class Foo {
      readonly int _bar;
      readonly string _baz;
      public Foo(int bar, string baz) {
           _bar = bar;
           _baz = baz;
      }

    public int Bar
    {
        get { return _bar; }
    }

    public string Baz
    {
        get { return _baz; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use object initialization syntax:

```
var foo = new Foo() { bar = 7, baz = "a" };
```

It requires your fields to be public and properties to have a setter.

Compiler will translate it into following code:

```
var temp = new Foo();
temp.bar = 7;
temp.baz = "1";
var foo = temp;
```

Comment: Updated my answer to reflect that. Thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 0):

I'd use properties instead of fields - it's easier to modify in the future if you need to add logic to the properties.

```
class Foo 
{
      public int Bar { get; private set; }
      public string Baz { get; private set; }

      public Foo()
      {
      }

      public Foo(int bar, string baz) 
      {
           Bar = bar;
           Baz = baz;
      }
}
```